# 俺で悪かった meaning?

Tags: particle-で, reading-comprehension

Context: Two characters are about to kiss, when the guy leans in the girl stops him and says it

> 知ってますよね? 私こういうのしたことないって!

Don't you know it? I never did these kinds of things

So the guy start to laugh and the girl says

> からかってるんですか?

Finally, the guy answers this to her:

> いやいや笑ってない. 初めてが俺で悪かった

to which the woman replies

> 違っ！　そうじゃなくて　びっくりしただけ!

I'm stumbled on how to take the guy reply.  俺で悪かった rather than my fault he seems to be saying "your first kiss being with me would be bad"?

Answer (score 2):

悪い/悪かった can mean *I'm sorry* (or something like 'too bad'), which is the case here (cf [悪い](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%82%AA%E3%81%84/#je-82048) #11).

> 初めてが俺で悪かった

means "I'm sorry about your first kiss being with me".

Comment: But would it work even if she stopped him? Given they didn't kiss

Comment: @Bluegate More or less yes. You can read it as *your first kiss was almost with me*. Again, it is about the whole context that is not provided, but the meaning of the sentence should be the same (the rest is a matter of translation).